# Application freezes with FMDB execute update query

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, fmdb

I am using FMDB wrapper class for database in my iphone app.

App freezes many times when i call a class with database execute update query.

Sample :

```
    BOOL success = [database executeUpdate:@"UPDATE JOBTABLE SET ST = ? WHERE jobid = ?",@"Accepted",[NSNumber numberWithInt:[jobIDStr intValue]]];
```

I am trying tested this by adding logs before and after this code.
In console the line before its is printed, and then the app freezes.

I am calling function which includes this line of code from other class.

I had tried call this method using below code as well

```
Addjob *addjob=[[AddJob Alloc]init];
[addjob performSelectorInBackground:@selector(addJobHttpRequest) withObject:Nil];
```

This has also not worked for me. The function addjob contains the database update query.

Comment: can you paste `addJobHttpRequest` function code

Comment: You can hit the 'pause' button in XCode when the app is in the frozen state, and have a better look at where its frozen (usually an infinite loop/recursion). The code seems ok, calling the method in the main thread is the right way (a FMDatabase object should be used in a single thread).

Comment: shall i call it using [addjob addJobHttpRequest]; or the method using calling in background is ok.

Comment: @arthan.v this problem is not only with addjobhttp function, i have started facing this problem for most of the function in which database update is used.It was working fine previously.After IOS update, i think it has started giving this issue.

Comment: @TechFanatic presuming that you've created your `database` instance in the main thread, you may need to call (in not in the main thread) `[addjob performSelectorInMainThread:@selector(addJobHttpRequest) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`, or handle the query to get called in the main thread from inside `addJobHttpRequest`.

Comment: @alex-i i had tried with pause , its always stopping on update query itself. I want to call function with database query from other class.

Comment: @alex-i addjob performSelectorInMainThread:@selector(addJobHttpRequest) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; I had tried this as well still its hangs on that line of code. Previously it used to work properly.

Comment: @arthan.v can you give me link to sample how to use FMDB?

Comment: @TechFanatic please make a screenshot while xcode is paused, and with `Debugger Navigator` (on the left) visible (shows the call stack).

Comment: @TechFanatic, i guess some flaw in your function. May be infinite loop or something. Try printing NSLog before and after that line. use `breakpoints and NSZombie enabled`. and try printing `[database lastErrorMessage]` to find the problem

Comment: @alex-i Thanks for your help , i was able to solve the issue.

Comment: @arthan.v Thanks for your help , i was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AddJob.h

Create

```
    Addjob *addjob=[[AddJob Alloc]init];
```

And try accessing function .m file.

Comment: This also worked for me in many cases in my application, I was using this code in .m file.

Answer (score 0):

if([db open])

NSString *queryStr ;

```
    queryStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update yourTableName set DatabasefieldName = '%@' where serial=%i ",databaseFieldValue,serialValue intValue]];

    [db executeUpdate:queryStr];
```

Comment: Not good if you care about sanitization - for instance `txtDbFieldName.text` could be used to create an sql injection.